# Select failed from V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS when called from a procedure

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-19c

Assuming the following user with these privileges granted:

```
-- create admin user on CDB
CREATE USER c##myadmin IDENTIFIED BY myadmin DEFAULT TABLESPACE system QUOTA UNLIMITED ON system ACCOUNT UNLOCK
/
-- allow access to all PDBs to the admin user
ALTER USER c##myadmin SET CONTAINER_DATA=ALL CONTAINER=CURRENT
/ 
-- grant needed permissions
GRANT DBA to c##myadmin                            ;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO c##myadmin                 ;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO c##myadmin                   ;
GRANT EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE TO c##myadmin           ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOGMNR TO c##myadmin         ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$DATABASE TO c##myadmin          ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOGMNR_CONTENTS TO c##myadmin   ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$ARCHIVED_LOG TO c##myadmin      ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOG TO c##myadmin               ;
GRANT SELECT ON V_$LOGFILE TO c##myadmin           ;
GRANT RESOURCE, CONNECT TO c##myadmin              ;
```

Now, when I connected as my myadmin, I can run the following:

```
BEGIN 
  DECLARE v NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOGMNR.ADD_LOGFILE(LogFileName=>'/path/to/archive/log/arc0000013.0001', Options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.new);
  DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(StartScn=>23456789, EndScn=>23567890,  Options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG+DBMS_LOGMNR.NO_ROWID_IN_STMT);
  select count(*) into v from v$logmnr_contents;
END;
END;
/
```

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

but when it created as a procedure it failed with insufficient privileges:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure Test AS
 v NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
 DBMS_LOGMNR.ADD_LOGFILE(LogFileName=>'/path/to/archive/log/arc0000013.0001', Options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.new);
 DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(StartScn=>23456789, EndScn=>23567890,  Options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG+DBMS_LOGMNR.NO_ROWID_IN_STMT); 
 Select Count(*) into v from v$logmnr_contents;
END;
/
Exec Test
/
```

```
Procedure Test compiled


Error starting at line 9 in command -
BEGIN Test; END;
Error report - 
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "C##MYADMIN.TEST", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

If I comment out the `select` the procedure succeeds.

Is there an additional privilege to enable it to run the `select` from a procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-LOGMNR_CONTENTS.html#GUID-B9196942-07BF-4935-B603-FA875064F5C3)

> V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS contains log history information. **To query this
> view, you must have the LOGMINING privilege.**

The `LOGMINING` privilege was granted to `DBA` role. When running an anonymous block, all your privileges granted through a role are effective. When running a stored procedure defined with the default definers rights option, privileges granted through a role are ignored. The `LOGMINING` privilege should be granted directly to your user:

```
grant logmining to c##myadmin;
```

Comment: You are right. it works. but why it works without `GRANT LOGMINING` when it been called directly?

Comment: @SHR "When running an anonymous block, all your privileges granted through a role are effective."

Answer (score 0):

You need the ability to `REFERENCE` the table/view in order to include in a precompiled ptogram.

For trial and error testing ONLY, you could grant `ALL` permissions.  But, this is a serious security risk.

Comment: But why this table\view is different from other tables\views? for example: I can `select count(*) from v$database`

Comment: No, this is not correct. The `REFERENCES` privilege serves a different purpose.

Comment: "why this table\view is different from other tables\views?"  Because access to it has more security implications.